# Mono for android VS layout not showing

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I install mono and VS2010. No error shown after installation however both my mono develop and VS2010 has the issue with mono for android4.2.4. It cant dsplay the layout axml file heres the screen shot..

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why is your layout not showing, but you could try using another XML graphical editor as [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) to create your interfaces, and then copy the XML code to a XML layout file on your monodroid project.

Comment: i think xamarin didnt see this bug. I realy love to program in c sharp android but i guest i should go back to java.. Thanks

Comment: anyway the layout designing is the same in java and monodroid, they both use xml code to define the layout =)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 you can open the axml files with different xml editors, most of the times when you have an error like this it means something in the axml is not correct (i.e. no closing tag or a word misspelled) so it will not load the graphical designer. You can check your code by rightclicking the axml file and "Open with.." one of the non graphical editors, these have much better error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing that file and re-opening it. Sometimes that refreshes my layout previews.

Also, as Lieketjj said, you probably have some little error that causes the layout preview not to load.